# How to properly union different IQueryables and then serialize them in JSON

Tags: c#, linq

I've 2 different data sources. Let's say, for example, that one source contains ids and lastnames and second source contains other ids and lastnames. I want to combine them in JSON like this:

```
{
  "Full": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "lastname": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "lastname": "Smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve it I'm trying "Union" Ids from different sources, then 
"Union" lastnames from different sources and after that, "Zip" it in one anonymous typed variable called "full".

```
        var ids = idsFromOneSource.Union(idsFromOtherSource);
        var lastNames = lastNamesFromOneSource.Union(lastNamesFromOtherSource);

        var full = new
        {
            Full = ids.Zip(lastNames, (i, l) => new { id = i, lastName = l })
        };
        return JsonConvert.Serialise(full);
```

Where **idsFromOneSource**, **idsFromOtherSource** are `IQueryable<int>` and **lastNamesFromOneSource**,  **lastNamesFromOtherSource** are `IQueryable<string>`

I'm getting this error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.Int32,System.String]] Zip[Int32,String,<>f__AnonymousType2`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.String,<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.Int32,System.String]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

For serialization I'm using NewtonSoft Json.net, but looks like the problem not in it. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: When you say "difference sources": are they both coming from the same Entity Framework context?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, yes they are. I saw you reply below and I'll try to solve it like you suggest. Thanks for reply.

Comment: If the IDs and LastNames are together in OneSource, why are you separating them?

Comment: @JamesCurran, they're in different tables in database. As I get it, I've one context for one database. But I'll try to unify ids and lastnames from each source as StriplingWarrior suggest.

Comment: Are the Ids unique or overlapping? Because this sounds more like a case for Concat than for Union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `Zip` within linq-to-Entities.  You *could* convert them to linq-to-objects calls by calling `AsEnumerable`:

```
    var ids = idsFromOneSource.Union(idsFromOtherSource);
    var lastNames = lastNamesFromOneSource.Union(lastNamesFromOtherSource);

    var full = new
    {
        Full = ids.AsEnumerable().Zip(lastNames, (i, l) => new { id = i, lastName = l })
    };
    return JsonConvert.Serialise(full);
```

but one caveat that you may be aware of is that the collections need to be aligned exactly (in the same order).  It seems like it would be safer to have some key to join the different sets together.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but looks like AsEnumerable() doesn't work. Still getting "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method" I'll think about keys as you said.

Comment: It's still giving the error on `Zip`?  That's odd because it should be binding to `Enumerable.Zip` and bypassing EF altogether.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fall. I retried and It's working! Thanks you and @StriplingWarrior. You guys are so amazing so I don't even know which answer mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`Zip` isn't supported in LINQ to Entities. While you *could* try to materialize the values prior to invoking `Zip` (as D Stanley shows), it's probably not a good idea to rely (as `Zip` does) on values matching up between your two queries, especially because `Union` will match things differently if one source of last names has some of the same values as the other source of last names.

I'd recommend rethinking your source queries to see if you can just select the IDs together with the Last Names from each source. Wherever you're storing last names, there should be some relationship between those last names and the IDs, right? Because that's how Relational Databases are supposed to work, right? `Union` should work on complex types as long as they have exactly the same shape, so something like this ought to work:

```
var idsAndFullNames = idsAndFullNamesFromOneSource
    .Select(src => new 
    {
        id = src.ID,
        fullName = src.FullName
    })
    .Union(
        idsAndFullNamesFromOtherSource.Select(src => new
        {
           id = src.Id,
           fullName = src.full_name
        })
    .ToList();
```

But if your sources are not coming from the same Entity Framework context, you'll need to materialize the two sources so that the `Union()` happens in-memory:

```
var idsAndFullNames = idsAndFullNamesFromOneSource
    .AsEnumerable()        // force LINQ-to-Objects to take over
    .Select(src => new 
    {
        id = src.ID,
        fullName = src.FullName
    })
    .Union(
        idsAndFullNamesFromOtherSource.Select(src => new
        {
           id = src.Id,
           fullName = src.full_name
        })
    .ToList();
```